# Evitar registros em duplicidade em uma determinada coluna MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho um sistema de leilão onde vários usuários podem dar lances, mas estou com um problema quando ocorrem lances ao mesmo tempo, pois são inseridos no banco de dados com o mesmo valor na coluna `bidding_price`, ex:

> 0.02
>   0.02
>   0.02

Eu montei um select que retorna todos os lances com valores iguais (duplicidade) para um determinado leilão:

```
SELECT bidding_price, count(*)
    FROM bid_account
    WHERE auction_id = 1335
    GROUP BY bidding_price
    Having Count(*) > 1
```

Nesse caso ele vai retornar as duplicidades para o leilão com ID 1335.

A estrutura da tabela `bid_account` esta dessa forma:

```
id | int(255) - índice - primária - AUTO INCREMENT
auction_id | int(11) - id do leilão
bidding_price | float(20,2) - valor do lance, ex. 0.02
```

Eu cheguei a criar um DELETE que consegue apagar as duplicidades, porém seria injusto com algum usuário, ter o lance apagado por um erro do sistema. Segue:

```
DELETE ba
    FROM bid_account ba JOIN
         (SELECT ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price, MAX(ba2.id) as max_id
          FROM bid_account ba2
          WHERE ba2.auction_id = ?
          GROUP BY ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price
         ) ba2
         ON ba2.auction_id = ba.auction_id AND
            ba2.bidding_price = ba.bidding_price AND
            ba2.max_id > ba.id
WHERE ba.auction_id = ?;
```

Esta com `?` ali por que ele recebe o valor por um parâmetro.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver este problema, evitando que seja inserido o valor igual na tabela `bidding_price`, porém para um determinado leilão identificado pela coluna `auction_id`?

Na tabela existem vários valores iguais em `bidding_price`, porém o que não pode ocorrer é valores iguais para o mesmo leilão, ou seja, para o mesmo valor em `auction_id`.

Eu pensei em criar um update, que verifica antes se existem duplicidades, se houver ele atualiza os valores inserindo 1 centavo a mais em cada duplicidade. Mas acho que iria da problema quando houve 3 lances ao mesmo tempo.

Esse comando SQL será executado em node, e irá rodar em um cron a cada segundo, ou seja, a todo momento ele estará realizando essa verificação. Se houver um lance duplicado agora, no próximo segundo ele vai identificar e corrigir.

O sistema de lances funciona em conjunto com um cronômetro regressivo de 15 segundos, sempre que alguém realiza um lance o cronômetro volta a sua contagem inicial de 15s.

Comment: Basta criar um índice UNIQUE e ver se deu falha no insert, e essa idéia de cron a cada segundo é furada. Melhor trabalhar com um código que suporte paralelismo e eventos/sinais.

Comment: Índice único e "transactions" rápidas , tratando o erro de duplicidade.

Comment: Infelizmente surgiu um problema, ele até iria funcionar mas o que ocorre é o seguinte: cada lance realizado ele cria uma nova linha que contém o valor e a ID do leilão. Se eu colocar UNIQUE para as duas colunas, como que ele vai inserir a próxima linha com a mesma ID do leilão? E tem casos onde haverá leilões diferentes com o mesmo valor. Ai o UNIQUE não iria funcionar para nenhuma das colunas. Ou existe algo que pode ser feito para contornar essa situação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta que você use o `UNIQUE`, tal forma que:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD UNIQUE INDEX(`bidding_price`, `auction_id`);
```

Dessa forma o par de `bidding_price` e `auction_id` são únicos, então se for `{0, 0}` não poderá existir outro igual, mas ainda poderá existir `{0, 1}` ou `{1, 0}`. Então para cada `auction_id` apenas irá existir um único `bidding_price`.

Você pode testar isso no [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96ea19/1).

Comment: @Inkeliz...E como faço para ele retornar algum alert para o cliente se já houver algum lance com o mesmo valor? E se acontecer do lance ser realizado exatamente no mesmo instante o que ocorre, ele não registra nenhum?

Comment: Consegui aqui, valew, não achei que algo tão simples fosse resolver o problema, parabéns!

Comment: Infelizmente surgiu um problema, ele até iria funcionar mas o que ocorre é o seguinte: cada lance realizado ele cria uma nova linha que contém o valor e a ID do leilão. Se eu colocar `UNIQUE` para as duas colunas, como que ele vai inserir a próxima linha com a mesma ID do leilão? E tem casos onde haverá leilões diferentes com o mesmo valor. Ai o `UNIQUE` não iria funcionar para nenhuma das colunas. Ou existe algo que pode ser feito para contornar essa situação?

Comment: O `UNIQUE` é aplicado ao par, não para cada um separado, como expliquei na resposta. O `UNIQUE` irá prevenir uma inserção onde os dois valores `bidding_price` e `auction_id` são iguais. Então, se eu posso *dar um lance* de 1 para A e 1 para B e também 2 para A, mas eu não posso dar *um novo lance* de 1 para A, porque duplica. Isso está explicado em https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html, você pode fazer um teste simplesmente dando dois `INSERT teste VALUES (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)`, todos vão funcionar, mas se incluir um novo (1,1) irá falhar...

Comment: Você pode testar isso em http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96ea19/1.

Comment: Nossa, show de bola heim, funcionou mesmo! Me tira mais uma dúvida, como seria para deixar essas tabelas configuradas dessa forma no `CREATE`? Seria dessa forma? `PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `bidding_price` (`bidding_price`,`auction_id`)`

Answer (score -1):

Você pode verificar no SQL se existe algum lance com o mesmo valor usando [`CASE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp):

```
CASE  
    WHEN ? IN (SELECT bidding_price FROM bid_account WHERE auction_id = ?) 
    THEN INSERT ...
```

Comment: O problema é que o lance é inserido tudo ao mesmo tempo, não tem como verificar antes se já existe algum registro.

Comment: O problema então é a linguagem escolhida, talvez o node não seja a linguagem ideal para o que deseja fazer. Da uma olhada [nesse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtDwdoxQL4A), é possível mudar o tamanho do pool de thread para 1, mas a idéia do node é justamente fazer mais de uma coisa ao mesmo tempo

Answer (score -3):

O que interessa é quem dá o commit primeiro. E isso nunca se dá ao mesmo tempo, diferença de milissegundos. O que acontece é que precisas aumenta o cache de armazenamento de insert do mysql para criar uma fila. Depois disso, cada nova requisição deveria fazer reload na página do cliente ou ao menos jogar os dados atualizados com o timestamp num arquivo json e ir modificando a div (ou outra tag qualquer) dinamicamente e só a parte do preço. Podes fazer isso com uma api rest ou ajax.